# How to access MongoDB remotely

Tags: mongodb

I don't have `MongoDB` installed locally. Mongo is installed on `linux` box and I have to verify the connectivity from my windows 7 machine. What `client/shell` can I use to do that? Is it possible to do this without doing full Mongo installation.

Comment: You can also connect directly with the mongo shell to remote instances

Comment: @Sammaye tool recomendation, unfortunately, are off topic on SO, mongo shell is a tool. I deleted my answer based on your comments!

Comment: @at0ma indeed that is why I put a quick comment and voted for its closure

Comment: @Sammaye is Mongo shell a separate tool other than mongo installation?

Comment: Nah it ain't, but it is easy to scrape from a download of the MongoDB binary to put on multiple machines

Comment: @mpm My understanding is with putty, I can log onto server, how can I verify connectivity of db running remotely from my system. Please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully and quickly connect to remote Mongo instance using [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/)